# android handler thread takes more time when screen is off

Tags: android, service, foreground

i wrote a simple app which has a Activity and a service(run In the foreground). The service need to do a periodical job,so i create a handler, and send the handler message periodically.

```
class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case 1:
            // do my job here
            this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 15000);
        }
    }
}
```

I think my job should execute every **15s**, and never ends as long as my service not killed by user.

but when i exit the activity (long press menu key, sweep out the activity) and turn screen off.  My job seems get executed at a random interval(all longer than **15s**) , sometimes even longer than **1 minute**.

I think this is probably relative to android system power policy.

how can i make my job execute at a fix interval in such circumstance. Pleas help.

Answer (score -1):

When you remove your activity from **Recent Activity list**, the process finishes by android framework. So, your `ServiceHandler` should stop processing.

As good practise, developer should add code to `stop` such service processing in `onDestroy()`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my handler is created in the service which is set    to froeground priority. and i expect it continue running after the main activity removed, i expect the handlerthread keep looping and process message periodically. If i'm wrong, is there a better way to archive my goal? Could you please give me some clue thanks.